# Should i use 'malloc(0)' or 'free() and then set variable to NULL'? What's better?

Tags: c++, type-conversion, malloc, user-input, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am currently writing a function that prohibits the user from entering unnecessary characters, and writes numbers to an array, and then converts from the array to `int`, then returns. I want to make a function based on a dynamic array. The algorithm is as follows: I enter a number, the array expands, erase the number, the array shrinks. The problem appears when the string is empty after erasure and waits for a number to be entered. How should I proceed in this case? Use `malloc(0)` or use `free()`, and then set the pointer equal to `NULL`?

Can I just set the pointer to `NULL` and thereby clear it? Probably, the answer is no I can't, because I think memory cells are still filled with data, but I want to hear more detailed answers.

Is my implementation of the idea bad?

At the beginning of the code, there is a comment, if the number exceeds the value `2147483647` then the algorithm behaves strangely, have any ideas why this is happening?

Sorry for the questions, but it is really driving me nuts. I searched the entire Internet and did not find any answers to my questions, even on StackOverflow and in the proposed duplicates.

```cpp
long long int number_input(int limit)
{
    // Limit set the number of digits in the number

    // !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    // I have no idea why is that happening 
    // 2.147.483.647 = 2147483647
    // 2.147.483.648 = -2147483648
    // -2.147.483.648 = -2147483648
    // -2.147.483.649 = -2147483647

    char c;             // current entered symbol   
    int length = 0;     // length of number (digit capacity, minus included), but index for digits is length - 1
    char* number_array_pointer = NULL;
    long long int number_array_integer = 0;
    int index;      // index for converting string to integer


    if ((number_array_pointer = (char*)realloc(number_array_pointer, sizeof(char) * length)) == NULL) {
        cout << "Fatal: failed to allocate " << sizeof(char) * length << " bytes.\n";
        abort();
    }

    for (;;) {
        c = _getch();
        if (c == 13 && length != 0) {       // Enter breaks down the loop
            if (number_array_pointer[0] == '-' && length < 2) {
                continue;
            }else {
                break;
            }
        }
        else if (c == '\b' && length != 0) {    // Backspace
            cout << "\b \b";
            length--;
            if (length == 0)
            {
                // malloc(0) vs free() then ' = NULL'
                if ((number_array_pointer = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * length)) == NULL) {
                    cout << "Fatal: failed to allocate " << sizeof(char) * length << " bytes.\n";
                    abort();
                }
            }       // We cannot realloc 0 bytes
            else if ((number_array_pointer = (char*)realloc(number_array_pointer, sizeof(char) * length)) == NULL) {
                cout << "Fatal: failed to reallocate " << sizeof(char) * length << " bytes.\n";
                abort();
            }
        }
        else if (c == 45 && length == 0) {      // Minus for negative number
            length++;
            if ((number_array_pointer = (char*)realloc(number_array_pointer, sizeof(char) * length)) == NULL) {
                cout << "Fatal: failed to reallocate " << sizeof(char) * length << " bytes.\n";
                abort();
            }
            number_array_pointer[length - 1] = c;
            cout << c;
        }
        else if (c > 47 && c < 58 && length < limit) {      //  Allow to enter only digits
            length++;
            if ((number_array_pointer = (char*)realloc(number_array_pointer, sizeof(char) * length)) == NULL) {
                cout << "Fatal: failed to reallocate " << sizeof(char) * length << " bytes.\n";
                abort();
            }
            number_array_pointer[length - 1] = c;
            cout << c;
        }
        else {
            continue;
        }
    }

    if (number_array_pointer[0] == '-') {
        index = 1;
    }
    else {
        index = 0;
    }

    for (index; index < length; index++)
    {
        number_array_integer *= 10;
        // get the actual digit from ascii code
        number_array_integer += (long long int)number_array_pointer[index] - 48;
    }

    if (number_array_pointer[0] == '-') {
        number_array_integer *= -1;
    }

    free(number_array_pointer);
    return number_array_integer;
}
```

Comment: `free()` is the proper function provided for the purpose. With `malloc()`, `"If size is 0, then malloc() returns either NULL, or a unique pointer value that can later be successfully passed to free()."` The call to `realloc (ptr, 0);` for an allocated `ptr` is equivalent to calling `free (ptr);` (and yes, missed the C++ tag, use `new` and `delete` as `malloc()` knows nothing about constructing objects)

Comment: Neither. Use `new` and `delete` in modern c++.

Comment: @NikitaDemodov that's not any better. This just needs an `std::vector`.

Comment: Fun fact: `sizeof(char)` is always 1. Even when `char` is not 8 bits.

Comment: Your code is way more complex than it needs to be to illustrate your question. You have input validation intertwined with memory management and loop control. Delegating separate tasks to separate functions would make your code cleaner, and make it easier to dummy-up an example that focuses on just the subject of your question (tedious manual memory management).

Comment: @OP *The algorithm is as follows: I enter a number, the array expands, erase the number, the array shrinks* -- Why not simply enter the entire data, whether it's digits or not, and then afterwards, remove the illegal characters from the string?  That takes 3 lines of C++ code, not 50 lines of complex C code.

Comment: *I searched the entire Internet and did not find any answers to my questions.* -- The Internet has billions of web pages -- either your approach is wrong, or you have skipped over any possible answers that are available.  What you are asking for can be accomplished in a very small function.

Comment: [Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c72ef2d5de69d512).  Compare that example to your attempt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the answer to your second part as to why things go off-track if the number exceeds the value `2147483647`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main() {
  std::cout<<"The answer is "<<std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
}
```

[Output](https://godbolt.org/z/vG16W4KWq):

```
The answer is 2147483647.
```

That's the maximum value of a 32-bit integer (the usual `int` on platforms is 32-bit).

As to your first part, please use [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) if there's no inhibition on using it! I'll let someone else answer that.

Comment: But in my case, I use long long int, and The answer is 9223372036854775807. What I miss?

Comment: @StarMadePresent Try adding logs in the loop where `number_array_integer` is being constructed from `number_array_pointer` and check at what limit does the conversion fail.